# Sign with the debug key on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, flutter

I haven't configured signing in gradle file and I released my app to Google Play successfully.

Upload certificate on Google Play:

```
SHA1: B5:E0:B6:51:92:27:09:2E:C2:6A:BF:BF:5F:94:82:C5:2E:BF:12:08
```

debug.keystore file:

```
androiddebugkey, 2017/9/24, PrivateKeyEntry,
(SHA1): B5:E0:B6:51:92:27:09:2E:C2:6A:BF:BF:5F:94:82:C5:2E:BF:12:08
```

I realized that I released my android app to Google Play with a debug key and somehow the Google Play Console couldn't detect that it was a debug key.

Today I want to update my app, the Google Play Console reject my file. (Signing in debug mode)

Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Google accept only release key the debug are not accepted because they have no information about the developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) you can contact Play Console support and they can help you change your keys (see the steps to take at the bottom of the article).

If you didn't use Google Play App Signing there is nothing you can do except re-publish your app under a different package name.

A good reason to use Google Play App signing.

Answer (score 0):

> `Create release keystore/jks file and create build from this and you can upload build successfully on play store`
>
> refer this link
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: I can't create a new key.  Google Play Console rejected it. Because SHA1 is different.

Comment: Use your old keystore/jks file for exsisting app.

Answer (score 0):

For those who accidently used debug.keystore to sign your release, Google still let you convert your debug key to new key! This happened to me and I was able to convert it. What you need to do is:

1. Create a production release from your Play Console
2. Opt-in to Google Play App Signing
3. On the App Signing tab, choose "Use existing key from Java Tool"
4. Follow the direction from there (Generate and upload private key of your debug key, create new upload key....)
5. Sign your app with the new upload key
6. Upload your app bundle to Play Console. Vola!